# How to check if two PictureBox have the same image?

Tags: c#

```
    var img1 = (pictureBox1.Image = Properties.Resources.dynamite);
    var img2 = (pictureBox2.Image = Properties.Resources.apple);
 if (img1 != img2)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("ok");
                        pictureBox1.Image = Properties.Resources.empty;

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("no");
                        Game_Over end = new Game_Over();
                        end.Show();
                    }
```

I want to create a simple game. If i hit a fruit the fruit picker is replace whit a empty picker and if you hit a dynamite to get game over

Comment: get the bitmap and compare each pixel.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35153895/6527049

Answer (score 1):

Convert the images  into byte arrays and then do the comparison of byte arrays.

Bytearray1.SequenceEqual(  bytearray2 ) can be true or false.

Comment: You can also use a hash function to compare the two byte arrays.