# Compare two image with c# and selenium webdriver

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, compare, selenium-chromedriver

I want to compare two images with c# and selenium webdriver to improve my tests. For example program is comparing two images and when the images are the same, program can move on.

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: You mean pixel by pixel comparison?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Compare images in c# is well written here:

[Algorithm to compare two images in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35151067/algorithm-to-compare-two-images-in-c-sharp)

You want to download img from webpage?

In selenium get all img tags and take src attribute. Download src of image using:

```
using (var client = new WebClient())
{
    client.DownloadFile("http://example.com/file/song/a.mpeg", "a.mpeg");
}
```