# How to compare the background image of a button reference?

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to compare the background image of previousButton(a button reference) to the background image of Bpown(a button) but the if will not work.

I have tried changing a button's background image to previousButton's BackgroundImage and it worked so it is not connected to the problem.

```
void click()
        {
            if (turn == true)
            {
                if (previousButton.BackgroundImage == Bpown.BackgroundImage)
                {
                    //unreachable code
                }
            }
        }
```

EDIT: This is a windows form project

Comment: `==` in this context will compare the references, not the actual images themselves. So if the same image was assigned to both it would be `true`, otherwise it will return false. It won't actually examine the image, if that's what you wanted.

Comment: This is the same image but thanks anyway :)

Comment: What are you targetting: Winforms, WPF, ASP..? 
YOU should __always__ TAG your questions correctly so one can see it on the questions page!

Comment: You say it's the same image, but if you've loaded the same image twice it wouldn't be the same image, this is checking that you've loaded the image once and assigned the same image to both

Comment: Do not try to compare image content unless you really need to. Instead use the Tags of the buttons to store hints about the images they show!

Comment: Have a look at these 2 posts: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/39980/determining-if-2-images-are-the-same  and  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35151067/algorithm-to-compare-two-images-in-c-sharp

Comment: NibblePig, I already made buttons to contain the backgroundImages so I can go `Bpown.BackgroundImage` to get the images, so I tried setting all the button images with the code like `button1.BackgroundImage = Bpown.BackgroundImage;` but it didn't work.

Comment: What does `same` means to you? Same name? Same look? Something else?